# Finding an integral subring of $k[x_1, ..., x_n]/P$ generated by $n$ algebraically independent elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R = k[x_1, ..., x_n]/P$, where $x_i$'s are variables and $P$ is prime. Suppose $R$ has transcendence degree $n$. I would like to find $z_1, ..., z_n \in R$ algebraically independent such that $R$ is integral over $k[z_1,..., z_n]$. This is the base case in the induction proof of Noether's normalization lemma in the book I am looking at. But it skips the details. Any explanation is appreciated!

Comment: Let $R_j=k[x_1,\ldots,x_j]/(P\cap k[x_1,\ldots,x_j])$, since $R_{j+1} = R_j[x_{j+1}]$, $TrDeg(R_{j+1}) \le TrDeg(R_j)+1$, if $x_{j+1}$ is algebraic over (the integral domain) $R_j$ then the transcendence degree is $\le n-1$, otherwise it is $n$ and $P=\{0\}$

Comment: @reuns I have been trying to deduce $R_{j+1} = R_j[x_{j+1}]$, but I haven't been able to. Could you possibly provide additional explanation? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by transcendence degree of $R$? Is this the transcendence degree of the field of fractions of $R$ over $k$? If yes, then the Krull dimension of $R$ equals $n$ and $P$ should be $(0)$.

Comment: @user26857 That makes sense! Thank you!